# Sequential workflow console application template missing in VS2010 Ultimate Beta2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow, console, workflow-foundation, sequential

I am using VS2010 ultimate Beta2 and under Visual C# -> Workflow -> I don't see the Sequential workflow console application or state machine console application

Could someone please advise why these are missing in VS2010. I am able to see them on VS2008 ->Workflow.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In VS2010 Pro RC1 the sequential workflow console app and state machine workflow console application are only available if you choose .Net Framework 3.5 in the combobox above the project types.

But why worry about beta 2, now that RC1 is out?

I would think that if this is a true and serious error, a bug report is probably better than a SO question.

Answer (score 1):

As Guge says this is by design (It's the same in Beta/RC or RTM). In Visual Studio 2010 you have 2 different versions of Windows Workflow. The new one (4.0) uses a new runtime under the hood and has a WPF look and feel. The designer/activities are different.

The old one (3.5) -also called Legacy- can only be created in Visual Studio 2010 if you change the target framework to 3.5 or 3.0. After you do that you will have the option of State Machine/Sequential WF Console App.

Note however that after you have created the 3.5 workflow you can retarget to 4.0. This will keep the same designer/runtime but it will be running under the 4.0 Framework. Everything will work as expected. 
If you try to upgrade and existing VS2008 project you will get the option of doing this.